# Doctrine mongoDB ODM field with multiple types

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-odm

I need to store integer and string values in one field. What type should I use in mapping? When I use string, I get integer values as string in my mongo documents.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `@ODM/Field(type="raw")` annotation :
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#doctrine-mapping-types

```
/**
 * @ODM/Field(type="raw")
 */
protected $value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the string mapping. Then in your getter for the field if you need to return different types. Use something like this

```
public function getTransgenderField() {
    if (is_numeric($this->transgenderField)) {
        return (int) $this->transgenderField;
    }
    return $this->transgenderField;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example with data? If you are meaning to need to have mixed types inside MongoDB, you can't do this with doctrine as there is no mixed type for a field as far as I'm aware.